# How to connect to remote MySQL server with sshuser and mysqluser being distinct

Tags: mysql, remote, connectivity

I'm trying to connect to a remote MySQL server via ssh so that I have write-access to export some data. At the moment I can do the following:

1. Connect to the remote MySQL using `mysql -u mysqluser -pPASSWORD -h HOSTIP DATABASENAME`
2. Connect to the machine using `ssh sshuser@HOSTIP`

**(Note that HOSTIP is the same for ssh and mysql server, but mysqluser and sshuser are different).**

However, I cannot connect to remote MySQL via ssh. I tried two things:

1. After ssh-ing into the machine, I tried `mysql` in the terminal but it is not installed.
2. I tried `ssh -L 1234:mysqlhost:3306 sshuser@sshhost`. However, I can only enter my `sshpassword`, after which I get ssh-ed in but no connection to MySQL still.

Comment: Haven't touched mysql in a while, but what do you mean by it's not installed after you SSH in? Have you updated the path environment variable such that you can see the mysql command? Can you change directory to mysql's bin and run it that way? If not you need to install the client first to access it.

Comment: After ssh-ing in, I tried `mysql` in the terminal but it is not installed. It's Mac with brew installed, so I tried `brew install mysql` but I got error `Error: Cannot write to /usr/local/Cellar
` I don't have root access.

Comment: I'm confused, is the machine you're trying to SSH into the mysql server? Then it should be installed.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to do SSH user@serveripaddress then click enter you will be prompting to enter password. please enter the same.

After that use **mysql -u root -p** then click enter you need to enter mysql password. If mysql is not installed in your server. Please install then get root password from DBA and then try.

Comment: Mysql is indeed not installed on the remote machine, but how is that possible? Doesn't this machine have  the mysql server on itself?

Comment: you need to install mysql manually in the remote machine so that you can able to access that..

Comment: what if I don't have sudo access? I'm only a user on that remote machine.

Comment: You need to get root credential for accessing Mysql..